# Finance app with cryptocurrency support?

Tags: finance, accounting, bitcoin, cryptocurrency

Is there any app that allows track spending in cryptocurrencies, mostly BTC?

I do some trading and need to record my activity with following features:

- transactions with special fields for crypto, fiat, rate, fee, BTC address, hash
- volume reporting, which shows accumulated trade volumes
- daily, monthly reports
- stats

Is there any personal finance app that allows recording cryptocurrency activity and categorize them by tags or categories: deposit, selling, sending, etc.

Comment: No special recommendation, as I'm not really active in that field – but does [this list](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/finance_crypto) have a matching candidate? Btw, you didn't mention whether it should be an Android app – or one for iOS, or a WebApp, or – ahem, doesn't MS meanwhile call their stuff "app" as well?

Comment: Gladly. If you find something that fits, please remember to [answer your own question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across one that may meet your requirements:

- [Cryptofolio](https://github.com/Xtrendence/Cryptofolio) - "Track your cryptocurrency holdings/portfolio with an open-source web, mobile, and desktop application, along with a self-hosted RESTful API. "

It enabes entering of activities e.g. buy, sell, transfer. May be try using the demo.

Comment: thanks, will check it. Is my understanding correct that the web-version of this app is self-hosted? and what about Andoid, is it local storage?